# VB and digiCamControl standalone library

Tags: vb.net, webcam

I am trying to build a simple VB application using the [digicamControl](http://www.digicamcontrol.com/) standalone library.

I am facing an issue where I cannot initialize the cameras connected to my PC.

Here is my sample code:

```
Imports CameraControl.Devices

Public Class Form1
    Public Property DeviceManager As CameraDeviceManager

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DeviceManager = New CameraDeviceManager()
        DeviceManager.UseExperimentalDrivers = True
        DeviceManager.DisableNativeDrivers = False

        DeviceManager.ConnectToCamera()

        For Each cameraDevice As ICameraDevice In DeviceManager.ConnectedDevices
            TextBox1.AppendText(cameraDevice.DisplayName)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Could you please advise me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sometimes the Form Load event isn't the best place for code. If you put your code in a button click handler instead, do you get a better result, or a least an error message that you can pass on to us?

Comment: Thanks Andrew.No luck with your suggestion as well. Nothing happens and no error message

Comment: I have just enabled all the Exception setings and i got the following:

Comment: LoadFromContext occurred
Message: Managed Debugging Assistant 'LoadFromContext' has detected a problem in ...

Comment: If you do a search for that error message you will see that it is not a problem - you should reset the exception settings. Have you tried asking in the digicamControl forums?

Comment: I have put a question there as well but no response yet... thanks once again Andrew